# hoverOut() interferes with drag function when dragging too fast in Raphael

Tags: javascript, performance, hover, raphael, drag

I have a shape that has hoverIn() and hoverOut() function and it can be dragged at the same time. My problem is when I drag too fast (not like really really fast), the mouse pointer may go outside of the shape boundary before the shape is actually moved. This cause hoverOut to be fired and it messes up with my dragging function. When I drag slow, this doesn't happened since the shape displacement is small and the mouse is always inside.

How can I handle the fact that if I'm dragging I don't want to deal with hoverOut. I tried the unHoverfunction(), it partially worked but now after dragging and leaving the shape the hoverOut function is not fired as it should be.

Comment: Have a flag that you set isDragging when dragging, and check for that in your hover handler ?

Comment: Ok I thought there was a built-in solution, but yes that's what I did, Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a flag, it seems like no built-in solution exist. Thanks for your time.